# In Python, is there a method to print lists into a string using .format notation?

Tags: python, string, list, tuples, string.format

A simple Madlibs exercise:

```
STORY = "This morning I woke up and felt %s because %s was going to finally %s over the big %s %s."

WORD_types = ('an adjective','a pronoun','a verb','an adjective','a noun')

WORD_values = []

for s in WORD_types:
  print "Please give {}.".format(s)
  s = raw_input()
  WORD_values.append(s)

print STORY % tuple(WORD_values)
```

It's there a way to accomplish that last line with .format notation?

```
STORY = "This morning I woke up and felt {} because {} was going to finally {} over the big {} {}."

WORD_types = ('an adjective','a pronoun','a verb','an adjective','a noun')

WORD_values = []

for s in WORD_types:
  print "Please give {}.".format(s)
  s = raw_input()
  WORD_values.append(s)

print STORY.format(WORD_values)
```

This kicks back the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Madlibs.py", line 12, in <module>
    print STORY.format(WORD_values)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `*` to unpack the list:

```
print STORY.format(*WORD_values)
```

**Example Output:**

```
Please give an adjective
 optimistic
Please give a pronoun
 I
Please give a verb
 drive
Please give an adjective
 scary
Please give a noun
 hill
This morning I woke up and felt optimistic because I was going to finally drive over the big scary hill.
```

Here is the relevant documentation: [**Unpacking Argument Lists**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) and **[Format examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples)**.